# JavaFX: Why do my HBox children sometime overlap?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have this really strange problem. Let me try to explain:

[My Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgLXf.png)

I created a class called `NumberPicker`, which basic idea is taken from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/javafx-numbertextfield-and). The idea is to extend `HBox`, put a `Label` in it and another `VBox` with 2 `Button`s in it. In the end, it should look like this: (see (1) on My Image)

This is my code:

```
public class NumberPicker extends HBox {

    private Label label = null;
    private VBox vBox = null;
    private Button incrementButton = null, decrementButton = null;

    private String valueFormatString;
    private Number value;
    private Number stepWidth;
    private boolean isFloat = false;

    public Number getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public NumberPicker(Number startValue, Number stepWidth, String valueFormatString) {
        super();

        this.valueFormatString = valueFormatString;
        value = startValue;
        this.stepWidth = stepWidth;

        if (value instanceof Float) {
            isFloat = true;
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        label = new Label();
        label.setFont(Font.font(20));
        label.setText(String.format(valueFormatString, value));

        vBox = new VBox();

        //partially taken from https://dzone.com/articles/javafx-numbertextfield-and
        int ARROW_SIZE = 4;

        Path arrowUp = new Path();
        arrowUp.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(-ARROW_SIZE, 0), new LineTo(ARROW_SIZE, 0),
                new LineTo(0, -ARROW_SIZE), new LineTo(-ARROW_SIZE, 0));
        arrowUp.setMouseTransparent(true);

        Path arrowDown = new Path();
        arrowDown.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(-ARROW_SIZE, 0), new LineTo(ARROW_SIZE, 0),
                new LineTo(0, ARROW_SIZE), new LineTo(-ARROW_SIZE, 0));
        arrowDown.setMouseTransparent(true);

        NumberBinding buttonHeight = label.heightProperty().divide(2);

        incrementButton = new Button();
        incrementButton.prefWidthProperty().bind(label.heightProperty());
        incrementButton.minWidthProperty().bind(label.heightProperty());
        incrementButton.maxHeightProperty().bind(buttonHeight);
        incrementButton.prefHeightProperty().bind(buttonHeight);
        incrementButton.minHeightProperty().bind(buttonHeight);
        incrementButton.setOnAction(handler);

        StackPane incPane = new StackPane();
        incPane.getChildren().addAll(incrementButton, arrowUp);
        incPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        decrementButton = new Button();
        decrementButton.prefWidthProperty().bind(label.heightProperty());
        decrementButton.minWidthProperty().bind(label.heightProperty());
        decrementButton.maxHeightProperty().bind(buttonHeight);
        decrementButton.prefHeightProperty().bind(buttonHeight);
        decrementButton.minHeightProperty().bind(buttonHeight);
        decrementButton.setOnAction(handler);

        StackPane decPane = new StackPane();
        decPane.getChildren().addAll(decrementButton, arrowDown);
        decPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(incPane, decPane);

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().addAll(label, vBox);
    }

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = (ActionEvent event) -> {
        if (event.getSource() == incrementButton) {
            if (isFloat) {
                value = value.floatValue() + stepWidth.floatValue();
            } else {
                value = value.intValue() + stepWidth.intValue();
            }
        } else {
            if (isFloat) {
                value = value.floatValue() - stepWidth.floatValue();
            } else {
                value = value.intValue() - stepWidth.intValue();
            }
        }
        if (isFloat) {
            label.setText(String.format(valueFormatString, value.floatValue()));
        } else {
            label.setText(String.format(valueFormatString, value.intValue()));
        }
    };

}
```

So the thing about this is that if I create a `HBox` and fill it like this:

```
    HBox pickers = new HBox();
    NumberPicker np1 = new NumberPicker(1, 1, "%d");
    np1.init();
    Label label = new Label("TEST");
    NumberPicker np2 = new NumberPicker(1, 1, "%d");
    np2.init();
    pickers.getChildren().addAll(np1, label, np2);
```

the result looks like: (see (2) on My Image)

which is just really weird for me. The first `NumberPicker` looks fine, the second does not. It gets weirder: If I use a `Button` from the `NumberPicker`, the `Button`s jump a bit to the right and it looks like the other, correct `NumberPicker`: (see (3) on My Image)

I got no idea what the problem is. I tried to analyse with ScenicView, which got me following information:

```
NumberPicker: prefWidth 22,00
    Label: prefWidth 10,78
    VBox: prefWidth 30,00
```

This tells me that the `NumberPicker` should have a computed `prefWidth` of 41 since the sum of the widths of its children are around 41, but its actual value is 22. Once I click a `Button` the `prefWidth` value changes to 41.

Can somebody please help me figure this out? I obviously want the `NumberPicker` to look fine (like (3) in My Image) without having to click a Button first.

Btw. sorry for the strange thingy with the Image. SO does not allow me to post more than 2 links with reputation below 10

Comment: Try [Spinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html) component. Why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @MBec
Wow, good point. I didnt know about that component - JavaFX Scene Builder does not show it. Thanks, I will try it out. 
Anyway I would like to know what's wrong with my approach

Comment: Update SceneBuilder to newest version then it will have more components.